# How many assistant professor or postdoc jobs do people usually apply for in mathematics?

Tags: mathematics, job-search

Assuming you want a good chance of getting at least 1 offer from a research university, is applying for 20 jobs average? Is applying for 30 jobs overkill?

Would most letter writers feel hassled by having to send off letters to like 10-15 different websites, or would they expect that is normal?

Comment: This would depend strongly on the candidate and their strengths and weaknesses. For some people 20 can be overkill, for others 40 or 50 wouldn’t be enough, so I would caution you against relying on anyone’s generic estimate that isn’t based on a detailed knowledge of your specific situation.

Comment: It depends too much on the state of the economy, both the general economy and the academic economy at the time. It could be as many as hundreds spread over years. I finished at a time when there were almost no openings so it took a long time to get any position and even longer to get a good one. Moreover, what is "usual" this year might vastly different next year. Had I finished my degree two years earlier they would have been beating down my door.

Comment: I know it's not quite on topic, but it's fascinating to me how divergent the math academic and industry job markets are these days. Most math PhD graduates have to work extraordinarily hard to get a basic postdoc in a good university, but if they spend a couple of months pivoting into industry the tables are completely turned and its companies desperately competing for them. There must be some interesting economics or social science research to be done on this phenomenon!

Answer (score 11):

1) Unless you have something close to an Annals level paper, I would say you should be applying for close to 100.  This probably isn't actually possible; to hit this number reasonably, you have to apply for temporary positions and for non-research oriented positions.  Think of it this way.  Positions taking applications on Mathjobs are getting something like 500 applicants.  You're probably more qualified than most applicants, but if you're in the top 100, and a position hires uniformly at random from the top 100, then you need to apply to 100 to have expected value of one job.

2) Most recommenders are willing - they're blaming the university for not taking Mathjobs applications, not you.  If you want to save your recommenders trouble at the expense of your money, you can use Interfolio, which is a company that sends out applications - including confidential letters - for you.

Comment: Whenever I hear advice about applying to a hundred jobs, I wonder how many people are remotely competitive fits for a hundred jobs, especially in mathematics. Hiring committees don't hire uniformly at random from the top 100, so it seems that applying for a lot of low-probability jobs wouldn't actually increase your chances of getting hired.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning: Low probability is not zero probability.  It's common for hiring committees to have preferences that cannot be discerned externally, so some committee might have an interest in your application for reasons you don't know about - meaning that, a priori and externally, your probability for that job looks very low.  A large number of 1% chances add up.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning: From the internal point of view, with full knowledge, you aren't competitive fits for 100 jobs.  But you don't know, out of the 100 jobs you can apply for, exactly which 10 you will actually be competitive fits for.

Comment: Traditionally math has had more open searches rather than subfield-specific searches (though this is changing somewhat based on pressure from deans).  But because of this tradition, it's harder in math than in many other fields to know which schools you're a fit for.

Answer (score 7):

My opinion, which I think is far from universal, is that the tenure track and postdoc markets are quite different in this way.  Postdocs are hired to work with one or two particular faculty members, and so if there's no one close to your work at a school they're very unlikely to hire you as a postdoc.  If I'd made a list of the 10 most likely places to consider me for a postdoc, the places that were at all interested were a subset of that list.  Applying to only 10 would be unnecessarily risky, but I really don't think there's a huge difference in likelihood of success between applying to 20 postdocs and 100 postdocs.  By contrast, tenure-track hires are not expected to be as close to existing faculty, and there were several places that interviewed me that weren't on my most likely list.  Unless you're clearly in the top two or three people on the market that year (one Annals paper might not be quite enough), then you should literally apply to every single tenure-track position that you would consider taking.  20-30 places is way too few for the tenure-track market because there's just too much randomness in the process.

Answer (score 7):

I'm currently chairing the search committee for a tenure track position in applied mathematics at a smaller (not R1) research-oriented university.  We received 261 applications for the position and will phone interview about 5% of these applicants.  Many of these applicants have 5 or more years of experience past the Ph.D.

The academic job market in mathematics in the US is extremely competitive at this point- more competitive than in previous searches that I've been involved in over the last 20 years.  In this context, sending out far more than 20 or 30 applications would be entirely reasonable.

I agree with others that there is a big difference between the tenure track job market, the market for non-tenure-track but permanent instructor jobs, the market for term-limited non-tenure track teaching positions, and the market for research-oriented postdocs. However, you should probably not be too narrowly focused in your search.

If you're applying through mathjobs.org, then your recommendation writers can submit their letters online without having to write a separate letter for each application that you submit.  That really isn't an issue for those positions.  There aren't very many positions that aren't taking applications through mathjobs.org and would require separate letters.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, I would estimate about 25% of positions require letters outside of MathJobs.

Comment: Based on my experience, @brian-borchers has it right. It is very, very difficult to know you are a fit for a particular position. I've seen job ads which are virtually open as to research area, but present faculty members told me the hiring committee could only hire in specific area since it was "their" turn. "Fit" is *very* important, especially for smaller schools. After all, people are hiring someone they will work and socialize with for decades.

Answer (score 6):

The existing answers all seem to focus on the US job market, so I will try to put a perspective for the European job market and the differences here. Most US maths jobs are posted on MathJobs and one can apply there. This is convenient but also means that it is very easy to apply for a lot of jobs and so this is what people do.

Math jobs in Europe are not all aggregated in a single place. You need to find the job adverts on different job sites (possibly country specific ones), in some newspapers and on department websites. This also means the application process is much less uniform and each individual application will require a lot more work than a few clicks on mathjobs.org.

Knowing that, applying to 20 or 30 positions is sufficient, provided you actually are a reasonably good fit for each of them. In fact, it can be quite hard to even find that many positions that you are qualified for. For tenure track positions the teaching language is also a factor, so you can't just blindly apply all over the EU as in the US.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's also physically impossible to make hundreds of applications in Europe as they all require writing a response to different selection criteria, where it could take days to do one well.

Comment: @leacorv That is what I was trying to say. It is impossible to write that many applications. Fortunately it also works for you the other way round. A US institution will receive hundreds of applications for a position that all look reasonable at first glance. A Europan one will receive a lot less applications (at least of those that are worth reading in detail).

Comment: Great points!  Relatedly, there are also fewer colleges/universities in Europe (at least proportionally), since they're almost all large universities and there's nothing like the US liberal arts colleges.